# How to redirect a page while counting page hits?

Tags: redirect

I want to try an experiment with Facebook adverts. I want a page that redirects the user to an affiliate product. But I want the page to load the Facebook Custom Audience tracking pixel.

What redirect code will load the tracking pixel then redirect the user to the affiliate product page?

Comment: send status code=302 with an URL